# Container is overflow: scroll but I want some elements to overflow from it

Tags: css, overflow, css-position

I have a container that is set to overflow-y: scroll, and within it I have many elements. one of them, is a dropdown menu, and I want it to be able to overflow the container. it is already set to position: absolute, however, it is relative to elements within the container and not to the container itself so that won't work for me...

the container's css:

```
.container {
  position: static;
  border-radius: 24px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 71, 255, 0.4);
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 55dvh;
}
```

the dropdown menu css:

```
.dropdownmenu {
  z-index: 1000;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  direction: ltr;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 8px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 24px !important;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 95%;
}
```

again, there are sevral layers of elements within the container so the position absolute is relative to inner elements, NOT to the container, and I need it to stay that way.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Iv'e solved the issue with some elaborate maneuvering (however, from reading around it seems to be the best solution out there):

1. I've created a new component called PortalContainer like this:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const PortalContainer = ({ children }) => {
  const portalRoot = document.getElementById("root");

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, portalRoot);
};

export default PortalContainer;
```

2. I've wrapped the element I want to escape from it's parent (that has overflow: scroll) like this:

```
 <PortalContainer>
       <div
         ref={menuRef}
         style={{
           backgroundColor: colorScheme,
           boxShadow: `3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,255,0.1)`,
           top:
             dropDirection === "down"
               ? buttonPosition.top
               : buttonPosition.top - dropdownHeight - 100,
           left: buttonPosition.left,
           width: buttonWidth,
           transform: dropDirection === "up" ? "translate(0, 0)" : null,
         }}
         className={`${styles.dropdownmenu} ${
           showDropMenu === item.id ? `${styles.active}` : `${styles.inactive}`
         }`}
       >
         {options?.map((option, index) => {
           return (
             <button
               type="button"
               id={props.index}
               key={index}
               onClick={() =>
                 handleSelect(option.name, props.index, option.id, index)
               }
             >
               {option.name}
             </button>
           );
         })}
       </div>
     </PortalContainer>
```

this does the trick but I really wish they add a feature to css, to give a child element the option to escape it's parent even if the parent has overflow: hidden/scroll on it. something like :

```
.parent {
overflow: hidden;
} 
.child {
overflowEscape: escape;
}
```